# Should I (and if so, how can I best) enforce private abstract like method in php?

Tags: php, class, private, abstract, final

Looking for a little guidance here.

I know that private methods are not polymorphic and so it doesn't make sense make abstract functions of them, but I do want to somehow enforce that a child class of a base class always declares a private method.

Am I doing something wrong or is this okay? I know you can't do multiple inheritance so maybe traits are the way to go, but I don't know if I can enforce them in Php.

I was thinking, maybe I can have an abstract base class have an abstract protected method, and then have that class be final since the function has to be protected? The only downside is that I could go farther with this though.

I just want a child class to always have a base method that only it can access, but I'm not sure how to do that without making it final.

EDIT:

Situation context is I have a child classes that are like flyweights that inherit from a base abstract that do type checking (because php is dynamic) and also want to do a final check for required variables. Every child class has to do this and does it the same way, but it should be called by anything else.

EDIT Idea:

I was thinking I could just write an interface for the base class with a function to do the final function (in this case render), and inside function, I could call the error checking. The problem with this is that I could not access new attributes that I newly create in the extended functions because the base class function wouldn't know about them. Then I'd be stuck with putting them in an array or something which defeats the purpose of making the child class anyway. Also, if I did that, I couldn't be sure that the function didn't get redefined without making it final so that I could no longer extend it. Idk here. Please help if you have ideas.

Comment: You should never have the urge to enforce a `private` method on a class.
`Private` should be used in the object itself for doing whatever it needs to do. Everything you want to enforce needs to be public of course.
Can you post the situation in which you thing you would need that? If so it's possibly easier to help you...

Comment: So if I shouldn't enforce a private method, how can I enforce private functionality of the base class in child class without doing so in the constructor?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `interfaces` are for?

Comment: interfaces are for public members. Interface cannot define private members.

Comment: Well actually that's the point. `Private` indicates that it is a behaviour of the class itself - independent if it is beeing inherited or not. So you cannot enforce the implementation of a `private` method. For example: You can enforce a car to have the interface for accelerating and decelerating but you cannot and should not enforce how it does that. Because each type of car (gasoline, electric) handles the input of the driver in a different manner. Understand?
What's the situation where you thing you will need that?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but if you want an inheritable method that can't be called from outside the class, you simply want a `protected` method.

Comment: I see a usage of such thing: if a method of the base class relies on the fact that a derived class implements a method which is not exposed as public or protected. A typical example would be logging of an internal state or similar. What you can do is define a (non abstract) method in the base class that throws an exception if it is not overwritten by the inheriting class. This does make sense with "late binding".

Comment: @arkascha: I know languages where this beaviour is solved using explicit interface implementation. I don't think you can do this in PHP though...

Comment: @MarkusSafar Indeed, this does not seem to be possible. I recall from projects longer ago that I implemented a method in the base class that unconditionally threw a runtime exception, thus forced derived classes to overwrite the method. Only a crude workaround, but at least safe.